# will endless creation and running of Threads end up in a PermGen OOM?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, permgen

In my process I continuously create a new Thread object (subclass of Thread actually)  (up to several per second), run it and cleanly end.

I have noticed that when the process has been up for 25 days for instance, the process can die leaving a hprof behind, so that means an OOM. But the heap dump is tiny compared to allocated memory to the heap, so it probably is a PermGen OOM, and I am trying to find out the culprit.

I am not using any special jvm param barring -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Comment: +1 I don't know if you're really having a PermGen but... PermGen are a Sun specifities and Sun VMs have been plagued through the years with very-hard-to-diagnose-should-have-been-GCed-but-not-GCed PermGen issue.  The hibernate+Sun VM+Tomcat fiasco comes to mind.  Took **years** to diagnose on the Internet and people would each point fingers at each other telling *it-s-not-my-fault-it's{hibernate,Tomcat,Sun}-fault*.  But why always create new threads anyway?  Why not use some higher-level facility like a schedulor taking care of thread pooling/reuse for you?

Comment: I spawn a new Thread to do text extraction on files, using a 3rd party library, and to be able to terminate the thread if it hangs. Plumbing around is not very simple so not sure if I would be able to use a pool instead, though I understand the benefit.

Comment: I did that a lot (extracting data from file chunks in a multi-threaded scenario).  Make sure not to spawn too many threads.  I create a concurrent number of threads related to the number of available cores reported by Java.  Now if you can't dive into the API I understand you can't easily "plumb" this :)  In my case I was also the author of the data-extraction code so... :)  So basically I had a queue and a producer (one thread, reading file chuncks) and then 'n' consumers.  All this to be sure not too spawn too many threads yet use the most of all the cores available.

Comment: Are you redirecting stdout/stderror to a file? That file should contain "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" or "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" just to be sure.

Comment: @antispam, no, unfortunately we were not redirectem them to file when happened, and did not catch it either, so I saw no message about the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering this in order to bring closure. After much investigation, at least in my case, creation of very large number of thread **was not** the culprit of the OOM.

I ruled it out in two ways:

1. the issue was reported in another couple of instances and not many threads had been spawned in those cases.
2. I created a test where I spawned over 2.5 million threads (doing the normal work they do in our case) and got no issue of OOM.

So, the mere very large number of thread created is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your heap dump should certainly tell you the PermGen usage -- have you looked at it?

Anyway, if the classloader that loads a class is GCd, then the classes it loaded are GCd, too; generally this is the only way to unload a class. You should be thinking about using an application-level class loader, and periodically discarding it; that will prevent your memory issue.

Comment: no, I could not find that info, as far as I know there is no PermGen related info in the hprof. Also, I edited my question, maybe I did not explain clearly the Thread creation, it's the same class, new objects, all the time

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [jhat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) to look at the dump hat is produced, rather than just assuming that this is a perm gen problem? I'm not sure there's a direct correlation between the size of the hrof file and the size of the heap that is being dumped.

Comment: I am opening it with Eclipse memory analyzer. It's not the size of the file, it's the reported size of the heap dumped sorry.